# fullCalendarjs method fullCalendar('clientEvents') returns duplicate events

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

I am using [fullcalendar.io](http://fullcalendar.io)

I dynamically populate my calendar, by adding events via evenSources. Such as:

```
$('.add-more-events').on('click', function(){
    var myEventSourceUrl = // ... get the event source url somehow
    var eventSourceColor = // ... get the color for this source
    var eventSource = {
        type: 'GET',
        url: myEventSourceUrl,
        color: eventSourceColor
    };
    $('.my-calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', eventSource);
}
```

Likewise, I dynamically **un**populate my calendar, by **removing** events via eventSource. Such as:

```
$('.remove-some-events').on('click', function(){
    var myEventSourceUrl = // ... get the event source url somehow
    var eventSourceColor = // ... get the color for this source
    var eventSource = {
        type: 'GET',
        url: myEventSourceUrl,
        color: eventSourceColor
    };
    $('.my-calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', eventSource);
}
```

So far, so good: visually, events are appearing in the calendar (populated), & disappearing in the calendar (unpopulated) as expected. That is, whenever I click on the relevant button.

---

At some point, I want to reinitialize my calendar & redisplay the events that were last present in my calendar (keep the last eventSources I suppose).

Pseudo code would look like:

```
1. Back up my events
2. Destroy my calendar
3. Create & initialize new calendar
4. Add the backed up events (see step 1) to the new calendar
```

So I implemented the above such as:

```
var clientEvents = $('.my-calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents'); /* [1] */
$('.my-calendar').fullCalendar('destroy'); /* [2] */
$('.my-calendar').fullCalendar(calendarOptions); /* [3] */
var arrayLengthClientEvents = clientEvents.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLengthClientEvents; i++) {
    $('.my-calendar').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', clientEvents[i].source);  /* [4] */
}
```

But for some reason, I get duplicated events when calling `$('.my-calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents')`.

Note: it seems to be happening when switching weeks, not sure about this though, it may be unrelated.

---

#### Resources:

- [When using jquery fullCalendar, Why am i seeing duplicate events after switching months?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20341201/when-using-jquery-fullcalendar-why-am-i-seeing-duplicate-events-after-switching)
- http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Source_Object/
- http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/removeEventSource/
- http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/clientEvents/
- [filtering events with clientEvents method on fullCalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27040984/filtering-events-with-clientevents-method-on-fullcalendar)
- [JQuery Full Calendar - edit calendar view after initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18017325/jquery-full-calendar-edit-calendar-view-after-initialization)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ### [clientEvents](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/clientEvents/)
>
> Retrieves events that FullCalendar has in memory.
>   `.fullCalendar( 'clientEvents' [, idOrFilter ] ) -> Array`

So it returns an array of events.

You store it, recreate the FC and then **add the source of each event.** But the sources are URLs and **the same for many events**, so you get duplicates.

Basically you are doing

```
$('.my-calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', {url:"/myfeed"});
$('.my-calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', {url:"/myfeed"});
```

which will give you duplicates.

So to fix it, you could check for duplicates and not add them. Add the method below:

```
var filterOutDuplicateEventSources = function(allEventSources){
    var hash = {};
    var remainingEventSources = [];
    var arrayLength = allEventSources.length;
    for (var i = 0; arrayLength !== 0 && i < arrayLength; i++) {
        var currentEventSource = allEventSources[i];
        var currentEventSourceUrl = currentEventSource.url;
        if(currentEventSourceUrl){
            if(hash[currentEventSourceUrl] === 1){
                continue; //skip this event source, we've already added it
            }else{
                hash[currentEventSourceUrl] = 1; // remember that we add this currentEventSourceUrl
                remainingEventSources.push(currentEventSource);
            }
        }else{
            //handle non-url event sources
        }
    }
    return remainingEventSources;
}
```

Use this method such as:

```
// Get all event sources
var allEventSources = [];
var arrayLengthClientEvents = clientEvents.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLengthClientEvents; i++) {
    allEventSources.push( clientEvents[i].source );
}

// Filter out duplicated event sources
var remainingEventSources = filterOutDuplicateEventSources( allEventSources );
```

### Alternatively

Technically, I don't believe that `clientEvents` is meant to be used that way. What you really need is an `eventSources` method. But it doesn't exist (might be a good [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/list)).

I would likely try to store the calendar's event source state outside of fullcalendar. You said you have buttons that turn things on and off, are these basically toggles? Is it possible to determine the state by simply querying your various controls? Something along those lines might be a better solution. Maybe.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It confirms what I thought. I actually implemented such filtering strategy 5 minutes ago but I was hoping for a cleaner solution. `fullCalendar` could simply provide a hook to the `eventSources` really... implementing this filtering strategy really seems overkill.

Comment: `"You said you have buttons that turn things on and off, are these basically toggles?"` yes they are. `"Is it possible to determine the state by simply querying your various controls? Something along those lines might be a better solution. Maybe."` yes, I actually implemented this very solution at first & it was working, but it seemed stupid to me as it duplicates what (I suppose) `fullCalendar` does internally when adding & removing `eventSource` objects. Furthermore, getting these from the calendar seems more future-proof: i.e. we add/remove eventSources from other "triggers"

Comment: I created a feature request :) https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=2497&thanks=2497&ts=1430491524